# SAS HDD Clicking Noise in IDLE - Seeking Advice on PERC H710 Setup (Storage Troubleshooting)

Tags: hard-drive, debian, sas, clicking-sound

I recently acquired 5 used SAS HDDs with approximately 35 days of service each. It was a great deal compared to purchasing new HDDs, but there was a slight mix-up as I initially thought they were SATA. After some investigation, I purchased a RAID Controller (using it as HBA), the PERC H710. However, after installing everything, I noticed that these SAS HDDs are producing a strange clicking noise when in IDLE. I find it unlikely that all five disks, which were well-packed, have the same issue, especially considering the seller's good reputation. I've recorded the noise for reference:

Closer to the server:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/DFqMGDFCObU

In the other room (other side of the wall):
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/4jHKJnIhp2Q
PS: It might be challenging to hear from the video, especially with some SATA HDDs running. The server is in production, so there's ongoing read/writing on those other SATA HDDs.

Here's some info about one of them:

```
    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST33000650SS
Revision:             RS16
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c50055ad05e3
Serial number:        Z295A8NC
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Wed Feb 21 17:40:10 2024 EST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     48 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        68 C

Accumulated power on time, hours:minutes 63899:38
Manufactured in week 43 of year 2012
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  70
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  12281
Elements in grown defect list: 0
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with SAS HDDs before? Is this normal behavior for SAS, or should I run some tests? Any advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: The clicking sound is unlikely connected to the fact they are SAS HDDs. It is more to do with the fact the HDDs have been powered on for 7.30 years. Hopefully, you have a plan to deal with the age of the disks, as the issue you describe while solved by correcting the read errors is likely to eventually return.

Comment: Ohh jezz, you're right! I wonder why HDSentinel is saying 44 days:
HDD Device  0: /dev/sda
HDD Model ID : SEAGATE ST33000650SS
HDD Serial No: Z295A8NC
HDD Revision : RS16
HDD Size     : 2861588 MB
Interface    : SCSI
Temperature  : 42 °C
Highest Temp.: 42 °C
Health       : 100 %
Performance  : 100 %
Power on time: 44 days, 9 hours, 21 minutes
Est. lifetime: more than 1000 days

Comment: Now that makes sense! smartctl should be more acurate than HDSentinel, right? (I wonder why HDSentinel is this far off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after running the following command and waiting for it to finish, we have "total read errors corrected=1809673244" and the driver stopped making those noises.

```
smartctl -tlong /dev/sdX
```

Heres the output after completion:

```
root@abc:~# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-27-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST33000650SS
Revision:             RS16
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c50055ad05e3
Serial number:        Z295A8NC
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Thu Feb 22 09:40:48 2024 EST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     43 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        68 C

Accumulated power on time, hours:minutes 63915:46
Manufactured in week 43 of year 2012
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  70
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  12283
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate Cache) information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 3623441469
  Blocks received from initiator = 3686219937
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 272821687
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 36308955
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 15

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 63915.77
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 55

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   1809673244        0         0  1809673244          0      30248.740           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0       8554.361           0
verify: 2794696942        0         0  2794696942          0    1042801.370           0

Non-medium error count:    59813

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background long   Completed                  32   63907                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                  32   63890                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Background short  Completed                  32      23                 - [-   -    -]
# 4  Background long   Completed                  32      22                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 27600 seconds [460.0 minutes]

root@abc:~#
```

I hope this helps someone with the same issue!